# Ajax post posting twice but only need one

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using the following (added to DOM code) to update a MySQL db with like data, but, its posting twice and I have no clue why.

I have almost identical code for unlike which also posts twice so it kind of cancels itself out but twice as many DB hits than needed is never good.

```
html += '<script type="text/javascript">';
     html += '$(function()';
     html += '{';
     html += '$(".like").click(function(){';
     html += 'var element = $(this);';
     html += 'var I = element.attr("id");';
     html += 'var info = \'article_id=\' + I;';
     html += '$.ajax({';
     html += 'type: "POST",';
     html += 'url: "/pages/includes/ajax/like.php",';
     html += 'data: info,';
     html += 'success: function(){';
     html += '$(\'#like\'+I).fadeOut("fast");';
     html += '$(\'#unlike\'+I).fadeIn("slow");';
     html += '}';
     html += '});';
     html += 'return false;';
     html += '});';
     html += '});';
 html += '</script>';
```

How can I avoid posting twice?

Comment: Why are you creating a string?  To answer your question we will need to see a little more of your code, especially the part that adds this to the page

Comment: Your click event will execute the same anonymous function multiple times if the code was added to the dom in multiple places. So make sure this code doesn't appear isn't appearing more than once in your page source

Comment: @JustinBicknell Thanks mate, I think you might have something there, looking into it, really appreciate the answer - if you want to add as answer I'll gladly accept

Comment: Hope it works! I've added the answer, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your click event will execute the same anonymous function multiple times if the code was added to the dom in multiple places. So make sure this code doesn't appear more than once in your page source.

Comment: Thanks again, kind of figured it out but not quite, tricky this